# Что нужно передавать в headers в Changelly API?

Tags: changelly

Уже несколько дней ломаю голову над тем, какие аргументы надо передавать в headers в Changelly API, но что бы я ни пробовал, ничего не получается.

```
X-Api-Key:  
Your API key (SHA256 from public key).

X-Api-Signature:
The query's serialized body signed by your private key according to the RSA-SHA256 method.
```

Я получил `Secret Key` и `API key` на https://pro.changelly.com/, но они не подходят.

UPD: Если точнее я не понимаю какие ключи и в каком формате надо передавать, потому что есть API ключи(secret и public), а есть ключи кошелька (private и public)

Comment: Ваша ссылка не работает...

Comment: Там же документация есть [https://api.pro.changelly.com/](https://api.pro.changelly.com/)

Comment: @Simon 
в ней я как раз и не могу разобраться, это из документации параметры, я не понимаю что в них надо передавать

Comment: Может Вы какой-то код приведете? Потому что из вопроса ничего особо не понятно. Вот пример с [аутентификацией](https://api.pro.changelly.com/#authentication), что там непонятного? И метку языка поставьте, по Вашей метке всего один вопрос, собственно Ваш же, его не увидит никто толком.

Comment: @Simon, спасибо, я пытался что то сделать на второй версии апи, на третьей все понятно
очень благодарен